# What is the main point in the Forward contracts definition?

Tags: forward

In Islamic Finance there is a contract called "Salaf" or "Salam" which is similar to Forwards except in time of payment which happens in the entering contract day (exactly unlike the Forwards).
Some people says It isn't Forward but some other include Salaf in Forwards for instance
Muhammad Ayub in "[Understanding Islamic Finance](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470030690.html)":

> Bai‘ Salam is an ancient form of forward contract wherein...

So the Question is which is the main point "Time of Delivery" or "Time of Payment" in Forwards?